# Windows10同士のBluetoothペアリングによる仮想COMポート通信

Tags: windows, bluetooth, シリアル通信

現在、Windows10搭載のタブレットとPCを、Bluetooth経由で通信させようとしています。
通信にはSPPプロファイルを使用して、仮想COMポート通信をしたいのですが、
上記PCをペアリングをしても仮想COMポートが作られません。
2週間前に、Windows10のタブレットと、Windows8.1のPCとペアリングした際は、問題なく仮想COMポートが作成されました。（しかし、今再び上記のペアリングを行ってみたところ、この端末同士でも仮想COMポートが作られなくなっていました。。。）

Windowsのドライバーが原因でしょうか？
どのようにすれば、仮想COMポートが作られるのでしょうか。

ご存じの方がいらっしゃれば、ご回答どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問者さんはもうここを訪れていないようですが、この記事 [Windows10同士でBluetooth接続して、シリ...](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14192264419) と回答紹介記事 [Windows を Bluetooth SPP Server として使用する方法](https://kokufu.blogspot.com/2014/02/windows-bluetooth-spp-server.html) が該当しそうです。要はどちらかのPCをサーバーモードに設定する必要があるようですね。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/forum/all/windows10%E3%81%AEpc%E3%82%BF%E3%83%96%E3%83%AC/f467253f-6bac-4ef5-adbb-4a51335f8eef?auth=1